# Want to put an head text banner with collapsing bottom with use of bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
if (x.className === "topnav") {
x.className += " responsive";
} else {
x.className = "topnav";
}
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700);
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pattaya';
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,300,200,500,600,700,800);
h1 {
font-family: 'Pattaya', sans-serif;
text-shadow:5px 5px 10px #663300;

}

h2 {
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}

p1 {
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
}

p2 {
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
font-size: 15px;

}

p3 {
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
font-size: 15px;
}

p4 {

  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;

}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 0px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 19px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #112;
}

.active {
  background-color: #990000;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li.right{
  float: right;
  }

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10.5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #990000;
}

ul.topnav li active {
  background-color: #990000;
}

ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(.mob) {
    display: none;
  }

  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.topnav li.right{
  float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: fixed;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.right{
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}

.videoWrapperOuter {
  max-width: 640px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.videoWrapperInner {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.videoWrapperInner iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 40.7em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color:gray
}

a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color:gray
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: red
}

a:active {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meata charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="Keywords" content="Beats,Hip-Hop,Rap,Stockholm,Sweden">
<title>Statos Productions</title>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li class="active mob">
    <a href="index.html">
      <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="beats.html">Beats</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="history.html">History</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="studio.html">Studio</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:17px;" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="right mob"><p4>Statos Productions</p4></li>
</ul>

<div style="padding:10px;margin-top:30px;background-color:#FFF;height:1500px;">
<h2>Confidence and Dj Technic made an track with the legendary Edo G!</h2>
<p3>4 of August, 2016</p3>
</br>
<p1>I only knew Dj Technic over the internet. He seem an nice dude. He and his friend Confidence, made an track togheter with G. Dot & Born. featuring the legendary rapper Edo G! First time I ever heard of Edo G, was his song "I got to have it",
way back in the 1991. So I was suprised that Dj Technic made skratches and Confidence on the beat, with there latest song "Makin' Tracks":
</p1>
</br>
</br>
<center>
<div class="videoWrapperOuter">
<div class="videoWrapperInner">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F8McUSZkE5k"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
</center>
<h2>I'm on a music video!</h2>
<p3>4 of August, 2016</p3>
</br>
<p1>Couple of months ago, Algato called me, to appering on a musicvideo that he casted, togheter with Critical. So I dressed up and he took the best part of me in the video! His song is "Mary" and you can see my face at 1:07.
</br>
</br>
</p1>
<center>
<div class="videoWrapperOuter">
<div class="videoWrapperInner">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QMtS6EiccGo"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
</center>
<h2>Im back!</h2>
<p3>3 of August, 2016</p3>
</br>
<p1>Its been a while. I was kind of lazy to promote my self into the net. But if you want to survive in this industry you must be self promoting, while you still can! Under these years, I have been workin some of my own projects and did some mastering to Pangaia Crew, who is an rapgroup from South of Stockholm. The results came out pretty good. Here is their video "Paradox":
</br>
</br>
</p1>
<center>

  <div class="videoWrapperOuter">
<div class="videoWrapperInner">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cppOsbK9vGg"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
</center>
</br>
<p2><center><I>&copy; Copyright Statos Productions 2016</I></p2>
</br>
<p1><a href="https://www.soundcloud.com/statos" target="_blank" alt="Soundcloud"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud"></i></a></p1>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</center>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the page I created. Thanks to one member here, he solved the problem with the .

My questions is now, is Im into bootstrap code, but do not understand it yet.

Two things I want in this page is an headbanner, there I will put Statos Production with red background. Then I want when u scrolling down, the head banner disappering but the navigation menu is still there. When you scrolling up, the head banner is appering.

then I want the same color like on the menu, be on the bottom but in collapse bootstrap code. I was looking on youtube and try to implement the code into it, but what ever I try, it dosent work. Either the nav bar disappering or the is totally gone, because I forgot to put  code before I wrote code for the menu. There on the bottom there I will put links from facebook, google+, soundcloud and etc. Make that page dymaninc. (sorry about my grammer, I have autism)

What ever I read or look the video, more I try, more I destorying my page.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? You shouldn't just paste your entire website in here, just the part with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im so sorry! My brain wasn't there. I understand now, make it simply. Here is an simplier code:

```js
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
if (x.className === "topnav") {
x.className += " responsive";
} else {
x.className = "topnav";
}
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700);
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pattaya';
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,300,200,500,600,700,800);
h1 {
font-family: 'Pattaya', sans-serif;
text-shadow:5px 5px 10px #663300;

}

h2 {
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}

p1 {
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
}

p2 {
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
font-size: 15px;

}

p3 {
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
font-size: 15px;
}

p4 {

  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;

}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 0px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 19px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #112;
}

.active {
  background-color: #990000;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li.right{
  float: right;
  }

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10.5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #990000;
}

ul.topnav li active {
  background-color: #990000;
}

ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(.mob) {
    display: none;
  }

  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.topnav li.right{
  float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: fixed;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.right{
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}

.videoWrapperOuter {
  max-width: 640px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.videoWrapperInner {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.videoWrapperInner iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 40.7em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color:gray
}

a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color:gray
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: red
}

a:active {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meata charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="Keywords" content="Beats,Hip-Hop,Rap,Stockholm,Sweden">
<title>Statos Productions</title>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li class="active mob">
    <a href="index.html">
      <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="beats.html">Beats</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="history.html">History</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="studio.html">Studio</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:17px;" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="right mob"><p4>Statos Productions</p4></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```